# Can I bind keys in a keyup function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have bound several keys to certain functions.  There will be a point in the application that those bindings should be temporarily disabled and then reactivated when exiting this temporary state.  I am able to bind the keys, enter the temporary state, unbind the keys, do stuff, rebind a single key, do stuff on the `keyup` event for that key, but rebinding the original keys is not working.  Is it possible to bind keys in a `keyup` function?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
function bindKeys() {  
    $(document).keyup(function() {
        if ( event.which == 27 ) {
            //stuff
        }
        
        if ( event.which == 32 ) {
            //stuff
        }
    
        if ( event.which == 37 ) {
            //stuff
        }
    });
}

function temporaryUnbind() {  
    $(document).keyup().unbind();
        //stuff
    $(document).keyup(function() {
        if ( event.which == 27 ) {
            //stuff
            bindKeys();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try `.on()` and `.off()`.

Comment: Why not `bind` your `function` with a `.keyup()` event and just wrap it into another function outside of `bindKeys`?

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely possible to do this by using `on`, `off`, and then `on` again.

It can be simpler to simply use `on` and then a flag in your code telling you whether to process things in the `on` handler.

Using `on`, `off`, then `on` again:

```
function handleKeyUp() {
    // Handle your keys
}

// When you should start handling the keys
$("some selector").on("keyup.myhandler", handleKeyUp);

// When you should temporarily stop handling the keys
$("some selector").off("keyup.myhandler");

// When you should start again (same as the original start)
$("some selector").on("keyup.myhandler", handleKeyUp);
```

Using a flag:

```
var flag = true;
$("some selector").on("keyup.myhandler", function() {
    if (flag) {
        // Handle your keys...
    }
});

// When you should temporarily stop handling the keys
flag = false;

// When you should start again (same as the original start)
flag = true
```